# Cannot get the public folder to work in meteor 0.3.7

Tags: meteor

All,
I have posted this as an issue on [Meteor's GitHub page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/196) a couple of weeks ago but got no answer. The issue appears so simple that perhaps nobody can believe me.

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue. I have created a brand new vanilla meteor project called "foo" using:

```
meteor create foo
```

I have created a folder 'public' in it and copied a picture in it (troll.jpg).

Then I have edited foo.html **exclusively** to display the picture. I see from meteor's examples that the URL corresponding to content in the public folder is simply / .

```
<head>
  <title>foo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="/troll.jpg">
</body>
```

I delete foo.js and foo.css that I don't use.

Then I start meteor and the page just shows a broken image placeholder. The web browser's console (Chrome 20.0.1132.47 for MacOS) says:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/troll.jpg". innerhtml.js:80
_htmlToFragment innerhtml.js:80
Meteor.ui.render liveui.js:33
(anonymous function) template.foo.js:1
ready startup_client.js:9
```

Using Safari I get the same. Meteor's examples on GitHub appear to work without issues. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

G.

Comment: Do you do anything special in your JS code? Does this also happen when you deploy it and test it from Meteor's server? Does it behave different if you do not include the / in the `src` attribute? I don't see anything obvious in your explanation that is going wrong and would suppose this to just work...

Comment: Tested as well now, non reproducible on Google Chrome on Gentoo, I'm however on the development branch. For me, I just get `image/png` as MIME type...

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have repeated the experiment on another Mac I have, and everything works there, and there are no MIME warnings.
I have tried reinstalling meteor and doing a 'meteor reset' of the app, but did not achieve anything this way.
So, it looks like my first Mac serves the image to the web browser with the wrong MIME header, but how is it possible?

Comment: Does your first laptop already have Node.js present on it? Different versions of that or the node modules might cause problems as well.

Comment: Yes I have another node installation and using modules through npm, but installed none globally (_npm ll_ in the meteor app folder shows "none"). Would you say it is worth uninstalling completely, just for the sake of the experiment? Other little software I've written in node, using Express for example, work nicely.

Comment: New findings! It is not a MIME issue. 

I believe that my instance of meteor cannot recognise that I am requesting content from the 'public' folder, and hence responds to the URL of the image like any other URL... that means returning the 'website' rather than the image.

The proof is that _curl http://localhost:3000_ and _curl http://localhost:3000/troll.jpg_ have the same identical output, that is a meteor-rendered web page!

What now? Where does meteor understand that an URL refers to public, and what can go wrong? (e.g. file permissions, case-sensitive file-system...)

Comment: That's very interesting, although I would have no idea as to why / how. :(

Comment: Is there any log file where I can see what the meteor embedded webserver is doing when processing the requested URL? Could we spot from there any errors / warnings that make the actual URL to the image ignored?

Comment: I doubt so, maybe the devs can troubleshoot this into detail with you. Try contacting deberg on IRC, if he's not around then tying `\`devs\`` lists the other ones (they re-use their Twitter handles as their nicks on the IRC[.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar issue where I thought it was serving font files as text/html mime-type, but it turned out that the route to my font file was wrong. Fixing the route fixed the problem.

It was confusing because the server should be returning a 404 error instead of 200 OK, but it works now.

Comment: Yes I would say that whatever the problem on my side is, it is an issue that Meteor does not log differently requests made to bad-formed / inexistent URLs to well-formed, existing ones. When using the development web server it should at least raise a warning every time an URL of the first kind is requested. My situation anyway is not about a wrong path in the code, as I've demonstrated by running successfully the same identical Meteor app on another Mac.